# ArcGIS Arcade Determining if a sorted array of numbers has consecutive numbers within it

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I have an array of numbers and want to determine the starting number and ending number of any numbers that are consecutive.  The numbers will always be in ascending order.

I would like to create a function that outputs an array which will look like these examples:

```
[1,2,3,5,6,7] = [[1,3],[5,7]]

[1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10] = [[1,2],[4],[6,10]]
```

I have made a few meager attempts but I'm just having difficulty with it for whatever reason.  I have attempted to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744537/javascript-how-do-i-check-if-3-numbers-are-consecutive-and-return-starting-poi) post with no success.

Comment: This is not a GIS question, you are better off searching on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: How is this not a GIS question? It’s an ArcGIS Arcade AGOL expression question which is directly related to GIS.

Comment: I understand both sides of the comments.  On one hand this is about Arcade, which only exists in ArcGIS software, which is GIS software.  On the other hand, Arcade is just a JavasScript derivative, and this question doesn't include an inherently geospatial component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arcade is heavily influenced by JavaScript, so it is good to look to JavaScript examples when trying to figure out Arcade issues that are non-geospatial in nature.  There might be a similar JavaScript example over at StackExchange/StackOverflow, but coming up with a code example was just as quick as searching around those sites.

The following code in [Playground | ArcGIS Arcade | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/),

```
var arr = [1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10];

var narr = [];
var sarr = [arr[0]];
for(var idx=1; idx < count(arr); idx++) {
    if(arr[idx] == arr[idx-1]+ 1){
        continue;
    } else {
        if(sarr[0] != arr[idx-1]) {
            Insert(sarr, count(sarr), arr[idx-1]);
        }
        Insert(narr, count(narr), sarr);
        var sarr = [arr[idx]];
    }
}
if(sarr[0] != arr[idx-1]) {
    Insert(sarr, count(sarr), arr[idx-1]);
}
Insert(narr, count(narr), sarr);
return narr;
```

yields,

```
    [ Array (2) , Array (1) , Array (2) ]
```

which expands to,

```
[ [1,2] , [4] , [6,10] ]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!